# Bash script trying to list files unsuccessfully

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm reading some file paths and names from a text file and trying to test if file exists. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but first echo returns filepath and file name whilst the echo inside the if statement doesn't. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    echo $line
    if [ -f "$line" ]; then
        echo "found: $line"
    fi
done < /mbackup/temp/images.txt
```

Comment: What does the echo inside the if statement print?

Comment: `grep -c $'\r' /mbackup/temp/images.txt` - Do you get `0` ?

Comment: @bubbles, Are you saying that you get no output from the second echo for ANY file, or are you getting  'found: ' with value of $line no being populated?  I can only imagine some unexpected characters somewhere in the fullpath name for the files.

Answer (score 0):

The only change is adding the **-r** option to read. That option is documented as:

> Backslash does not act as an escape character. The backslash is considered to be part of the line.  In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not then be used as a line continuation.

This helps prevent special characters in file names from interfering with your script.

I test this with files containing special characters and it works as you expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    echo $line
    if [ -f "$line" ]; then
        echo "found: $line"
    fi
done < /mbackup/temp/images.txt
```